# How to show single pop-up for whole guest session

Tags: theming, javascript, 7

In my site I want to place a javascript ad code( from Zedo) which is popping up one window for each page visit by the user which is quite nagging.

Ideally what I want is to pop up the ad after user leaves the site or closes the window.

At least I want is to show single pop up in the whole guest session.

I place the ad code before </body> in page.tpl.php but it gets executed for every page.

I'm thinking to make it better by using this logic:

```
if(time() % 3 == 0)
{
//javascript ad code here
}
```

At least this will reduce pop up by 3 times.

Are there any better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one cookie, if is the first time to the user enter into your page then create a cookie, when the user change of page you will check if the cookie exists and if exists don't show up the ad.

Comment: Will adding this cookie checking code affect caching of theme and template files in anyway?

Comment: No, if handle the cookie using javascript instead of php, with JS doesn't matter what kind of cache are you using in your project.

Comment: The ad code is getting executed by including a js file from the ad server. How do I wrap it with javascript function to get & set cookie? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I've created a question for code to include jquery code : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17729/wrapping-javascript-code-conditionally-using-a-cookie

Comment: ahh, i answer your question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/17762/4362

Answer (score 3):

You could set a cookie like this when the user first enters the site:

```
// php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['ad_zero'])) {
   // display your ad and set the cookie
   setcookie('ad_zero',1);
}
```

You could also use [jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) like this:

```
if($.cookie('ad_zero') != 1) {
  // display your ad and set the cookie
  $.cookie('ad_zero',1, { expires: 1 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I need more help with your second example. Before I saw your answer I already asked this question at : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17729/wrapping-javascript-code-conditionally-using-a-cookie

Comment: Finally I used this method but I was looking for the following solution and it worked only that for including another cookie plugin in Drupal, I find this method easier.