# Wrapping javascript code conditionally using a cookie

Tags: 6, theming, javascript

I want to include the following code in page.tpl.php only once during first site visit and for subsequently not. I mean this will pop-up an ad only once. I want to set it based on a cookie. How to conditionally include this code based on a cookie? I need the sample code.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        var zflag_nid="1185"; var zflag_cid="3307"; var zflag_sid="823"; var zflag_width="1"; var zflag_height="1"; var zflag_sz="15";
        </script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="http://d8.zedo.com/jsc/d8/fo.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

Will this work in page.tpl.php ? I want add it before </head> so that the js file is included only once in user session.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!jQuery.cookie('myCookie'))
    {
    $.cookie('myCookie':'myValue');
    <!-- Javascript tag: -->
<script language="JavaScript">
var zflag_nid="1185"; var zflag_cid="3307"; var zflag_sid="823"; var zflag_width="1"; var zflag_height="1"; var zflag_sz="15";
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://d8.zedo.com/jsc/d8/fo.js"></script>
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add javascripts files using javascript you need to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(!jQuery.cookie('myCookie')) {
    $.cookie('myCookie':'myValue');

    var zflag_nid="1185"; 
    var zflag_cid="3307"; 
    var zflag_sid="823";
    var zflag_width="1"; 
    var zflag_height="1"; 
    var zflag_sz="15";

    //building the script:
    var js = document.createElement("script");

    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src =  "http://d8.zedo.com/jsc/d8/fo.js";

    //inserting into the body document
    document.body.appendChild(js);
  }
</script>
```

Or you can use the  jQuery's  getScript function: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

You can look more in deep about this here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146

Comment: Thanks. This code has some small errors and the working one is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549616/loading-javascript-file-based-on-cookie-using-jquery/8549643#8549643 . Also Drupal default install does not seem to have cookie plugin so I can't use this code. For including a js file, we can user jquery native method: jQuery.getScript("..js");

Answer (score 1):

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317066/how-to-store-session-cookie-in-drupal-6-on-the-computer-of-the-visitor) should contain enough information to solve your issue.

I would go with the one that suggests using `setcookie()`. `$_SESSION` information is cleared when the user's session ends, generally at the close of the browser. Here is a recent example of me using cookies to remember an anonymous user's submission of a Webform and redirect them to the completion page if they tried to visit the Webform again:

```
    <?php
    define('REQUEST_TIME', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);

    function _mymodule_manage_cookie($nid, $type = 'my_cookie_type') {
      $matches = (bool) $nid == variable_get("mymodule_{$type}_webform_nid", FALSE);
      if (empty($_COOKIE["Drupal_visitor_mymodule_{$type}_submitted"]) && $matches) {
        mymodule_cookie_save(array("mymodule_{$type}_submitted" => TRUE));
      }
    }

    /**
     * Drupal 7 yoink!
     */
    function mymodule_cookie_save(array $values) {
      foreach ($values as $field => $value) {
        // Set cookie for 365 days.
        setrawcookie('Drupal.visitor.' . $field, rawurlencode($value), REQUEST_TIME + 31536000, '/');
      }
    }

    function mymodule_cookie_delete($cookie_name) {
      setrawcookie('Drupal.visitor.' . $cookie_name, '', REQUEST_TIME - 3600, '/');
    }
    ?>
```

You need to put this in a module or in `template.php` in your theme. You can conditionally include the code in a manner similar to the following:

*template.php*

```
    <?php
    function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
      // THEMENAME_get_first_visit_cookie() would refer to a function
      // you have to write that retrieves if the cookie
      // is set. You could alternatively try just using
      // $_COOKIE['my_cookie_type'].
      if (THEMENAME_get_first_visit_cookie()) {
        $variables['first_visit'] = TRUE;
      }
    }
    ?>
```

*page.tpl.php*

```
    (skip to wherever you want to embed the code)
    <?php if ($first_viist): ?>
      // Paste your code here
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Now, one more point. The way I just showed you *isn't* the best way. You should add your Javascript properly using `drupal_add_js()` in a module or by adding a separate Javascript file in the theme that reacts to a class on the `<body>` tag and displays your first visit message (or whatever you're doing). You would still need the `$first_visit` variable to determine whether to add the class or not.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use code on the server side and instead let me handle in the browser only. This is what I've asked.

Comment: Yes, then jQuery.cookie should help you. Test it to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your metaphors so to speak in trying to use jQuery and script tags like php if/thens to include code in your templates.

If you want it all done in the browser, then do it all in the browser, eg, if I haven't been here before, add or execute such and such code to/in the DOM, otherwise don't do anything, eg,

```
if ( ! // whatever you need to do in javascript to determine if you've been here before) {
  alert("Welcome New User!");
}
```

in your js.